# Flutter Provider: changes to List doesn't propagate

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a app with a `List<Match>` as state, which is kept in

```
 class MatchesChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
       List<Match> matches;

       refresh() async {
          matches = await MatchesFirestore.fetchMatches(); // goes to db
          notifyListeners();
       }
 }
```

then I have the following widgets (simplified)

```
 class AvailableMatches extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      var matches = context.watch<MatchesChangeNotifier>().matches;
      
      return Column(children: matches.map(e => MatchInfo(e)).toList());
    }
 }

 class MatchInfo extends StatelessWidget {
     Match match;

     MatchInfo(this.match);

     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // use match for a bunch of stuff
        return InkWell( 
           child: ...,
           onTap: () async {
           await Navigator.push(context, 
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MatchDetails(match)));
           await context.read<MatchesChangeNotifier>().refresh();
     } 
 }
```

In `MatchDetails` I have a bunch of buttons. One of them has this callback

```
    onTap() async => await context.read<MatchesChangeNotifier>().refresh()
```

When I tap this button I see (debugging) that

- `AvailableMatches` gets rebuilt (since it watches `matches`)
- `MatchInfo` gets rebuilt (since it's down the tree w.r.t. `AvailableMatches`)
- `MatchDetails` doesn't get re-built

Why is that? Is it because it is somehow called in the `onTap` function?

After I press the button I would like to see `MatchDetails` change when it's on top of the screen (i.e. the user is seeing it). Instead this doesn't happen

If I modify the way I push `MatchDetails` from `MatchInfo` with this ugly trick the thing works but I would like to avoid it

```
  await Navigator.push(context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
          MatchDetails(context.watch<MatchesChangeNotifier>().matches.firstWhere((m) => m.id == match.id))));
```

Comment: `matches.map(e => MatchInfo(e));` does not mutate `matches` and won't do anything since you discard the returned value. (If `matches` is an `Iterable`, also note that [`Iterable.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) is *lazy* and won't do any work until you access the returned values.)  `AvailableMatches.build` also fails to return a `Widget`, although I assume that's because you omitted code.

Comment: yes, I omitted some code. Now it should be more clear.

Comment: `matches` is changing, shouldn't the change propagate down to the single elements of `matches`? If this is not correct, how would you fix this code? Do I need to fetch a single element from the `ChangeNotifier` every time I need a single element of the list?

Comment: Does this problem still exist ?

Comment: yes, I am using the trick mentioned at the end to make it work